# Persistent sessions in Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

I'd like to add something like the "remember me" option into a Rails application and I need to create a persistent session that doesn't expire when the user closes his browser.
The only solution I found right now is to use a plugin:
http://blog.codahale.com/2006/04/08/dynamic-session-expiration-times-with-rails/

Are there any other (better) solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use cookies and set the expiration to a date very far into the future.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at how technoweenie's [restful authentication](http://github.com/technoweenie/restful-authentication/tree/master) does it.

Particularly [line 122 of the generator](http://github.com/technoweenie/restful-authentication/blob/2ae4c22f5a42100458f8be89c9f366b4099a4451/generators/authenticated/templates/authenticated_system.rb#L122) which allows login from a cookie.